# RMarkdown html_output error

Tags: r-markdown, rstudio-server

I am trying to create a RMarkdown document with RStudio using *shiny server*. It works fine if the ouptut is pdf but if I want it as html I get this following error at the end of the process (in the RMarkdown console I can see it reached 100%).

*Error: unrecognized fields specified in html_dependency: attachment*

I have no idea why this error is happening.
Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you

Comment: I got the same error after updating packages, and I simply had to update RStudio.

Comment: Updating RStudio did the trick...thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by a recent update of the relevant rmarkdown package or related ones.

Update RStudio to the latest version and then the error should disappear. It worked in my case.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem and found that it was caused by RStudio attempting to use Knitr to build a Shiny page. You can fix this by running using rmarkdown::run() instead of rmarkdown::render().  In some older versions of RStudio, the "Knit html" button runs this:

```
rmarkdown::render('filename.Rmd', 'html_document')
```

whereas, you can get the the results you want by running this command instead:

```
rmarkdown::run('filename.Rmd')
```

You could use this command **or just update to the latest version of RStudio.**

There is more info about authoring Shiny document here: http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_shiny.html.

Answer (score 0):

Updating RStudio didn't work for me. What did work was updating all R packages (`Tools > Check for Package Updates...`).

Comment: Reinstalling everything, updating, nothing worked for me. I was getting powerless and frustrated. What worked was deleting the project file and creating it again.