# R markdown error: can't produce HTML file

Tags: r, markdown, rstudio

I can't produce an HTML document from any .Rmd file by pressing the Knit HTML button in R Studio, including the sample document that summarizes and plots the cars dataset. Here's the error message that I get:

```
Error: unrecognized fields specified in html_dependency: attachment
Execution halted
```

However, I can produce the HTML document by running the command `knit2html("file.Rmd")`. The Knit PDF button also functions properly. Does anyone have an idea about how to fix this error?

Here's the sample .Rmd file that I have:

````
title: "Untitled"
author: "blakeoft"
date: "Friday, September 12, 2014"
output: html_document
---

A summary:

```{r}
summary(cars)
```
````

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example of the Rmd that produce this? I assume this is because RStudio uses **rmarkdown** while **knitr** uses **markdown** for rendering HTML.

Comment: updating rstudio could have fixed this indirectly, but updating rmarkdown would have worked

Comment: updating rmarkdown to 0.4.2 solved this issue for me as well

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I had the same problem which went away after upgrading to RStudio version 0.98.1056 (released 9 September 2014).

Comment: Can confirm, upgrading to 0.98.1056 fixed the issue for me as well.

Comment: Hmmm very strange since this was working always since yesterday:S thanks for pointing to this!

Comment: For me, updating to rmarkdown 0.3.3 fixed the problem. By the way, does anybody know where I can find previous versions of rmarkdown?

Comment: I had the same problem. I agree with George Dontas. I have Rstudio 0.98.977 and when I updated rmarkdown to 0.3.3, the problem went away

Comment: @GeorgeDontas I removed R 3.1.2 and reinstalled 3.1.0 (with rstudio) and I had rmarkdown 0.2.49, so that may be one way to find a previous version

Answer (score 4):

As I've answered [on another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29975595/1169233), updating RStudio didn't work for me. So I tried updating all R packages (`Tools > Check for Package Updates...`) and then it worked.